# Serializing ctype union

Tags: python, networking, serialization, union, ctypes

Is there a way to serialized ctype unions in order to send them over sockets? I’m trying to send a union over sockets to a network server but I am unable to serialize the data and it instead sends as an instance of the union object. Is it possible to use Python Struct() library to do this (I don’t believe it supports unions)?  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `bytes()` on your `ctypes.Structure` or `ctypes.Union`, you will get the underlying byte string that can be transmitted over a socket.  On receipt, copy that byte string back into the original object.

Here's a self-contained example.  The socket server is started as a thread and will send two objects to a client.  The client then receives the object and interprets it:

```
import ctypes
import socket
import threading

# Used to indicate what type of field is in the Union.
U32 = 1
DBL = 2

class MyUnion(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = ('u32',ctypes.c_uint32),('dbl',ctypes.c_double)

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1  # define before _fields_ to have an affect.
    _fields_ = ('type',ctypes.c_int),('u',MyUnion)

def client():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('localhost',5000))

    # Wrap the socket in a file-like object so an exact amount of bytes can be read.
    r = s.makefile('rb')

    # Read two structures from the socket.
    ex1 = MyStruct.from_buffer_copy(r.read(ctypes.sizeof(MyStruct)))
    ex2 = MyStruct.from_buffer_copy(r.read(ctypes.sizeof(MyStruct)))
    s.close()

    # display the correct Union field by type.
    for ex in (ex1,ex2):
        if ex.type == U32:
            print(ex.u.u32)
        else:
            print(ex.u.dbl)

def server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('',5000))
    s.listen(1)
    c,a = s.accept()

    # Prepare two structures
    ex1 = MyStruct()
    ex1.type = DBL
    ex1.u.dbl = 1.234
    ex2 = MyStruct()
    ex2.type = U32
    ex2.u.u32 = 1234

    # Send them as bytes
    c.sendall(bytes(ex1))
    c.sendall(bytes(ex2))

    c.close()
    s.close()

# spin off the server in a thread so the client can connect to it.
t = threading.Thread(target=server)
t.start()

client()
```

Output:

```
1.234
1234
```

Comment: I tried this however callin sizeof() on my structure prior to serialization returns 96, whereas calling sys.getsizeof() on the byte() serialization of the object returns 93

Comment: Likewise, simply calling getsizeof() on my struct returns 144, therefore is bytes() reducing my struct size as I need what I’m sending to be exactly 96

Comment: @John `ctypes.sizeof` not `sys.getsizeof`. The latter reports the total size of the complete Python object, not just the C structure it represents.

Comment: @John For the byte string result, use `len()`

Comment: @John Your structure is not shown, but you may have to deal with packing alignment as well.  For example, in my structure of a `c_uint32` (4 bytes) and a `c_double` (8 bytes), the default will be to add 4 bytes of padding between the parameters so the `c_double` is 8-byte aligned and total size is 16. You can avoid that by defining `_pack_ = 1` to get a total size of 12.  I'll add that to the example above.

Comment: Does packing alignment only come into consideration when calling bytes()? This would explain the variance in my size values

Comment: @John No you are using the wrong "sizeof" command.  You should get the exact same size for `ctypes.sizeof(obj)` and `len(bytes(obj))` if `obj` is a `ctypes` object.

Comment: Thank you Mark, always providing a great solution!